# GStreamer change of RTP PT value in CMD command

Tags: windows, cmd, gstreamer

I am using [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/index.html) on Windows, and want to start a local stream of my webcam with RTP PT 33. The command is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v mfvideosrc device-path="PATH TO DEVICE" ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay pt=33 ! udpsink host=localhost port=1234
```

But no matter what I do, the output always says that the payload is `96` and not the expected `33`.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong or what I should change?

The [documentation for gst-launch](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tools/gst-launch.html) explains the unusual syntax for the options on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pt=33` is not the correct way of setting the payload, instead try downstream caps:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v mfvideosrc device-path="PATH TO DEVICE" ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload=123 ! udpsink host=localhost port=1234
```

Here I set the payload to `123`, not 33 as you wanted in your question.
If you check [rtph264pay documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp/rtph264pay.html?gi-language=c#rtph264pay-page), payload range is set to [96, 127] (See the src pad definition), so any attempts to set values out of this range might be simply ignored by `rtph264pay`.